# Github force removal of bad file with backslashes

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I recently began using github and started playing with eclipse's git abilities, using some plugin (not sure which one added the functionality, might be aptana or git plugin). Somehow, the file's path got mixed up and posted to github as

```
src\com\XXXX\XXXX\SomeClass.java
```

instead of properly foldering into

```
src/com/XXXX/XXXX/SomeClass.java
```

There is no `src\com\XXXX\XXXX\SomeClass.java` in my local repo, and when I do a fetch it doesn't grab that file. How can I force it out of the listing on github?
I've tried removing `src/com/XXXX/XXXX/SomeClass.java`, committing/push, re-adding, and then committing/push again.

Comment: Is this a public repository? Can you share the link so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: It's a private repo. I took a screenshot to show what I'm talking about: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/63421730.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another contributer rebuilt the repo without the bugged files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using quotes? Might work, even if the file didn't sync.

```
git clone <url to your repo>
git rm 'src\com\XXXX\XXXX\SomeClass.java'
git commit -m "removed bogus file"
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. It only removed the legitimate files without removing the bad ones.